# Developing for Android vs developing for IOS

Tags: android, ios, similarity, difference

I have been working some time with Android and now considering a new job on iOS, so I was wondering how many new concepts would have to learn. I know iOS is another planet but this is just to clear a bit more the whole picture.

So, what are the similitudes and differences between developing an Android app and an iOS app?

Answer (score -1):

## Similitudes

Both use object oriented programming and have great IDEs with UI design implementation, nice features and the possibility of adding new ones.

## Differences

[image]

## Sources

General information:

http://www.androidauthority.com/developing-for-android-vs-ios-697304/

And some interest and more specific answers:

https://www.quora.com/How-does-Android-development-compare-to-iOS-development

I don't have much experience on iOS, so if something is wrong let me know and if you see an important missing similitude or difference, write it down as a new answer please!